# Why firestore service service account requires Firebase Admin and not Firebase realtime database admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I use a service account to interact with my firestore database (native/realtime mode) from my backend application.

I'm trying to reduce the privileges of the service account. When I set permissions to:`Firebase realtime database admin` all my calls fail with permission denied.

When I set them to `Firebase Admin` (i.e. access to everything, also image storage, functions etc) the api calls work perfectly.

P.s. since it's a service account it doesn't need security rules, so they are set as:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set permissions only to the database?

Answer (score 0):

For who has the same problem, I figured out the correct permission: `Cloud Datastore User`

This works even if you are using a firebase/native mode database **not** in Datastore mode.